# Nested array and objects are not properly converted to json

Tags: json, powershell, nested, slack-api

**Description**

---

Using `ConvertTo-Json` in *Powershell*, I am trying to convert the following object:

```
$richmessage = @{
    attachments = @(
        @{
            "mrkdwn_in" = @("text"; "pretext";);
            "title" = "title here";
            "title_link" = "http://somelinkhere/";
            "fallback" = "Summary of the attachment";
            "text" = "message";
            "color" = "red";       

        })      
}

write-host(ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $richmessage)
```

I expected to get this output:

```
{
    "attachments":  [
                    {
                        "text":  "message",
                        "fallback":  "Summary of the attachment",
                        "mrkdwn_in":  ["text" "pretext"],
                        "color":  "red",
                        "title":  "title here",
                        "title_link":  "http://somelinkhere/"
                    }
                ]
}
```

But the actual output is:

```
{
    "attachments":  [
                    {
                        "text":  "message",
                        "fallback":  "Summary of the attachment",
                        "mrkdwn_in":  "text pretext",
                        "color":  "red",
                        "title":  "title here",
                        "title_link":  "http://somelinkhere/"
                    }
                ]
}
```

**Notes**

---

- I want the `"mrkdwn_in": "text pretext"` to be `mrkdwn_in:["text", "pretext"]`
- If we take `$richmessage = @{ "mrkdwn_in" = @("text"; "pretext"); }` this will produce the array as expected, but when the array is nested like this: `$richmessage = @{ attachments = @( @{"mrkdwn_in" = @("text"; "pretext"); } ) }`; it concatinates the strings.
- I'm using this to post a rich message to *Slack* and allow mark downs in the attachments. (see [this link](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting))

**Question**

---

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding array value to the object separately

```
$richmessage= $richmessage["attachments"][0]["mrkdwn_in"] = @("text", "pretext");
```

Full example:

```
$richmessage = @{
    attachments = @(
        @{
            "mrkdwn_in" = ""; 
            "title" = "title here";
            "title_link" = "http://somelinkhere/";
            "fallback" = "Summary of the attachment";
            "text" = "message";
            "color" = "red";       

        })      
}
```

Comment: Already tried, still gives me the same result: `"mrkdwn_in" : "text pretext"`.

Comment: I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but this one is a syntax error (I'm running it on Windows PowerShell ISE). Remember this is Powershell script, not javascript or any other scripting language.

Comment: This is not correct. The issue is with depth, not formatting.